# Error in Zero inflated model (ziP) with bam

Tags: r, poisson, gam, mgcv

I am trying to use `bam` to run the following generalized additive model:

```
m <- bam(result ~ factor(city) + factor(year) + lnpopulation + s(lnincome), data=full_df, na.action=na.omit, family=ziP(theta = NULL, link = "identity",b=0))
```

But getting the following error:

> Error in bam(result :   extended families not supported by bam

The documentation for `bam` mentions the following:

> This is a family object specifying the distribution and link to use in
>   fitting etc. See glm and family for more details. The extended
>   families listed in family.mgcv can also be used.

The family.mgcv does include ziP. What am I doing wrong? Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Re-posting from r-help.

Sincerely,

Milu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the version of **mgcv** you are using does not support these extended families that are otherwise supported by **mgcv**'s `gam()` function.

Thankfully, the solution to your problem is trivial as Simon Wood has now implemented this feature (extended families within `bam()`) from version 1.8-19 as noted in the [ChangeLog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/ChangeLog):

> 1.8-19
>
> ** `bam()` now accepts extended families (i.e. `nb`, `tw`, `ocat` etc)

The current version is 1.8-22 which fixes some bugs related to the functionality you are looking for, so make sure you update to the latest version.

Here is an example modified from `?ziP`

```
 ## function to simulated zip data

 rzip <- function(gamma,theta= c(-2,.3)) {
 ## generate zero inflated Poisson random variables, where 
 ## lambda = exp(gamma), eta = theta[1] + exp(theta[2])*gamma
 ## and 1-p = exp(-exp(eta)).
   y <- gamma; n <- length(y)
   lambda <- exp(gamma)
   eta <- theta[1] + exp(theta[2])*gamma
   p <- 1- exp(-exp(eta))
   ind <- p > runif(n)
   y[!ind] <- 0
   np <- sum(ind)
   ## generate from zero truncated Poisson, given presence...
   y[ind] <- qpois(runif(np,dpois(0,lambda[ind]),1),lambda[ind])
   y
 } 

 library('mgcv')

 ## Simulate some ziP data...
 set.seed(1);n<-400
 dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
 dat$y <- rzip(dat$f/4-1)

 b <- bam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3),
          family = ziP(), data = dat)
```

Which gives for me, the following fitted model:

```
> summary(b)

Family: Zero inflated Poisson(-1.855,1.244) 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.97426    0.04988   19.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(x0) 2.396  2.989  2.336  0.0759 .  
s(x1) 2.784  3.464 77.217  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 7.397  8.317 59.364  <2e-16 ***
s(x3) 1.235  1.428  0.269  0.5888    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Deviance explained =   69%
fREML = 593.94  Scale est. = 1         n = 400
```

Comment: I'm using 1.8-33  (with an offset variable) and getting errors as well: Error in l1[!zind, 1] <- yp + lg$l1[!zind] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length